# Peer Channel File Transfer

Tags: c#, p2p, peer

I have a chat program written in C# using Peer channel technology 
but I want to extend the program to be able to send and receive files Peer to peer

how can i do this?

I use DefaultCustomResolver.exe and instance.exe  . every user open instance.exe

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Expose a method that takes a file path as an arguement and returns the file as a stream. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33825/WCF-TCP-based-File-Server) for a file server project in wcf. Although it doesn't take a p2p approach, i think it will be useful.